# emacs/Xemacs python Cygwin startup file error

Tags: python, emacs, cygwin, elisp, xemacs

I started using XEmacs in Cygwin and wanted to use it as a Python IDE. 
I found the required pluggins here:
http://gabrielelanaro.github.com/emacs-for-python/

but whenever I start xemacs it says

> cannot open load file:
>   /home/Owner/emacs.d/emacs-for-python/epy-init.el

my `.xemacs/init.el` looks like:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs.d/emacs-for-python")  
(load-file "~/emacs.d/emacs-for-python/epy-init.el")
```

My `.emacs.d/emacs-for-python` has `epy-init.el`and everything else that was extracted from the source provided in the website.

`xemacs -debug-init` shows a blank screen.

This is happening with every init file that i try to include

i tried a to init using a `sample.el` from
`http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Sample-_002eemacs-File.html`

and having init.el like:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs.d")  
(load-file "~/emacs.d/sample.el")
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: Is your directory really named `.xemacs.d` when you're trying to load from `emacs.d`?

Comment: no, sorry,  that was a typo, it is `.emacs.d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to load from `~/emacs.d/`, not `~/.emacs.d/`